# loop to check and remove image if not exist

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a loop which checks if an image with filename from database exists, if not to unlink all images because I have many duplicates in folder but folder is 50gb. I can't check each one.

So here's what I've tried

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT thumbnail FROM files WHERE id='$id'";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = $query->fetch_assoc();
$thumb = $row['thumbnail'];
$records = "../upload/images/";
foreach ($records as $record) {
    if (file_exists('../upload/images/'.$thumb)) {}
    else {
        @unlink('../upload/images/'.$thumb);
    }
}
```

**Update**

```
$sql = "SELECT thumbnail FROM filesWHERE id='$id'";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = $query->fetchAll();

foreach($sql as $search_result) {
    if(file_exists($search_result['thumbnail'])) {
        $img_source = ('../upload/images/'.$search_result['thumbnail']);
    } else {
        @unlink('../upload/images/'.$search_result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the code not working as expected?

Comment: @summea I think it's not properly, I'm newbie!

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, if this is a publicly accessible page you should be using prepared statements. If you do not use prepared statements it is a very serious security risk.

Comment: You're checking if the file exists and doing nothing. The else part doesn't make sense since the file doesn't exists. You're also looping through a string `$records` it should be $rows = $query->fetchAll() and foreach($rows...

Comment: @kojo7 No it's not public accessible, It's a mysqli which need to be more secure than mysql as I know that!
This error I have:
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in

Comment: @KeyneViana Yes if file exist to do nothing but if not exist to unlink image.This's my logic!

Comment: How would you unlink a image that doesn't exists? Describe more concisely what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @KeyneViana I don't know.I want to unlink images which not exist with filename in database, but existed ones to keep.

Comment: @kojow7 If file doesn't exists, delete it? That's whats the if/else says. It doesn't make sense. What you said leads to a completely different script. It would be necessary read the directory and list the images in order to compare to the database.

Comment: If the file doesn't exists in that particular folder, how can you delete it? :)
If file doesn't exists do you want to delete that record from DB table? Please clarify.

Comment: @Naresh Kumar Not existed images not inserted into database table with filename.
In database table only existed inserted.

Comment: @KeyneViana is correct. You are thinking about this the wrong way. You need to start with the image directory and find the files that do not exist in your database. You are trying to do it the other way around. If it doesn't exist in your database how will the $id be able to find the name of it?

Comment: @kojow7 I understand that I do wrong.
I've added code to post but I don't know whether correrct?

Comment: Let me rephrase the question.  Image you have an image $id of 999 and this id does not exist in your database. How will you pull the thumbnail name out of your database if 999 does not exist?

Comment: @kojow7 Yeah, actually if 999 not existed in DB it will return false.May I need to check one by one with loop as: first image with filename 1.jpg checked then goes to DB to check if this filename exist then if not exist unlink this image.Is this correct logic?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_GET` data directly into a query, this is a huge problem.

Comment: @tadman thanks for warning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the logic I've understood. Checking if there are files in the folder that aren't present in database, and if so, delete it.

```
$directory = "../upload/images/";
$images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");

foreach($images as $image)
{
  $sql = "SELECT thumbnail FROM files WHERE thumbnail =?";
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
  if($stmt) {
     $stmt->bind_param('s', $image);
     $stmt->bind_result($result);
     $stmt->execute();

     $stmt->fetch();

     if(!$result) {
        if(unlink($image)) {
            echo "Image deleted $image <br>\n";
        }
     }
  } else {
      echo "Unable to prepare SQL";
  }

}
```

Comment: Good! Though OP is using mysqli rather than PDO.

Comment: Yes I've get error with PDO!How to rewrite to mysqli this correct:

$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = $query->fetchAll();

Comment: @KeyneViana I've got this error:
Call to undefined method mysqli::bind_param().
Actually what is this in $sql at the end " =? "

Comment: Well, I'm not used to mysqli, but I've edited it, try now and see if it works

Comment: @KeyneViana Now this error:
Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object.
I've tried this on wamp I think not may a problem!

Comment: @KeyneViana unlink(../upload/images/../upload/images/1.jpg): No such file or directory - many times for each one image.

Comment: Now it's your time to correct the file path. I don't know where are your files.. It's a simple error.

Comment: @KeyneViana I don't know why folder is appears two times.I've changed to upload/images/ and nothing appear even error ?

Comment: Well , now it's a problem with the mysqli, right now I don't know why you're getting this. Check if the query is right. The "?" is the parameter assigned with bind_param().  Post another question with this code to see if anybody can help you

Comment: @KeyneViana Ok it work but it removed whole images and I've got message echo image deleted with filename of image!

Comment: Well debug it and see what's causing the problem. The logic is already made for you

Comment: Just a hint! Check how are you storing the thumbnails names, if it's only the image name like "1.jpg" or the whole path "../upload/images/1.jpg". If it's only the image name you should edit the bind_param line and extract from the $image variable just the last part that correspond to the image name so that it can search properly in the database.